# How to do refund request on CCAvenue with JSP?

Tags: jsp, ccavenue

I have implemented CCAvenue payment gateway for an order but If I want to refund for that order from CCAvenue how I can do that?? 
Please suggest, or it would be better if somebody having implemented code.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: I didn't write any code till now,I was just getting started with this.

Comment: Well then, get started and show us some effort, and we'll assist further